# three.js - How can I dynamically change object's opacity?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

This is my object:

```
var object = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "image.png" ) } ) );
object.position.set(2, 3, 1.5);
```

now after I've created this object in init(); function, I can directly go to the object and change his position,like this:

```
object.position.x = 15;
```

Now the question is how can I change the opacity of the texture???

Thanks :-)

Comment: I think it's good to keep [these](https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-cs291/l-91376562/m-103530762) in mind when using opacity feature. It is material from a course so you may need to watch previous videos but they are short.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

`THREE.MeshLambertMaterial` extends `THREE.Material` which means it inherits the `opacity` property, so all you need to do is access the material on your object, and change the opacity of the material:

```
object.materials[0].opacity = 1 + Math.sin(new Date().getTime() * .0025);//or any other value you like
```

Also note that the material must have it's `transparent` property set to true.

```
object.materials[0].transparent = true;
```

(Thank you Drew and Dois for pointing this out)

**Update**

the property is now simply [`material`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/Mesh.material):

```
// enable transparency
object.material.transparent = true;
// set opacity to 50%
object.material.opacity = 0.5;
```

Comment: Thanks George...I guess you my three.js GURU ;-)... I found my own solution,it took me a while...but again it's the best way to understand it well

Comment: Note that you must set `material.transparent = true` as well as the `opacity`.

Comment: `0.5 + 0.5*Math.sin(new Date().getTime() * .0025);` might be better ;)

Comment: As of R69, I had to use `THREE.Object3D.material.opacity` to change an object's opacity at runtime.

Comment: The comment on the "transparent" attribute should be included in the answer.

Comment: Does still work? my "object" doesn't have a materials property it has material instead?

Comment: @QurakNerd Thank you for pointing that out: I've updated the answer accordingly. (Can't believe it's been almost 9 years since I posted this)

Answer (score 13):

```
var map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( myJSONObject[i].url );
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { map: map, transparent: true } );
var object = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

material.opacity = 0.6;
```

Comment: how about a bit of an explanation?

Answer (score 9):

I know this question is very old but I wanted to give my answer from what I used in case someone needs it. With three.js, I used tweening through Greensock's TweenMax/TweenLite. With that, I was able to tween any property of any object and it ran smoothly. Check out the library [here](http://www.greensock.com/get-started-js/). All I needed to tween the properties was:

```
TweenLite.to(object, duration, properties);
```

where duration is in seconds and properties are in an object. The "gotcha" for this, especially while using three.js, is to make sure you get specific with the object parameter. For example, per this question, if you are changing the opacity of a mesh, you cannot do

```
TweenLite.to(mesh, 2, {material.opacity: 0});
```

rather, you need to be more specific and write

```
TweenLite.to(mesh.material, 2, {opacity: 0});
```

I hope this helps someone. Tweening is really awesome!