# three.js transparent geometry

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I have some geometry - with this code I can make them visible or unvisible:

`THREE.SceneUtils.traverseHierarchy( selArr[i], function ( obj ) { obj.visible = true; } );`

Is there a possibility to make a object transparent this way, so i can see an other object behind?

Comment: Have you tried using a material with an alpha channel on the object that should be transparent? [See this question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8502150/three-js-how-can-i-dynamically-change-objects-opacity)

Comment: The problem is that I want to switch the transparency on and off by a keyboard event. I tried obj.material.opacity = 0.5 but i think only the wireframe get transparent.

Comment: I have the solution i create a new material: `obj.material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial ({ color: 0x900000, transparent:true, opacity: 0.5} )`